# A question on deriving d'Alembert's formula from change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let's assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \ge 0$. I am asked to find d'Alembert's formula to the wave equation $$\begin{cases}u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0 & \text{in } \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) \\ u = g, u_t = h &\text{on } \mathbb{R} \times \{t=0\} \end{cases}$$ by changing the variables like this: $$\xi=x+t \text{ and }\eta = x-t.$$

At some point in my work (see below), I arrive at $$u(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+G(\eta).$$ When we back-substitute the variables, we have $$u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t).$$

This may be a really simple question to ask, but why is it not $u(\color{#00FF00}{x+t,x-t})=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$?

**My work so far:**

Solving $u_{xy}=0$ gives the general solution  $u(x,y)=F(x)+G(y)$, where $F,G$ are arbitrary functions.

Now system solving $\xi=x+t$ and $\eta=x-t$ for $x,t$ gives $x=\frac{\xi+\eta}2$ and $t=\frac{\xi-\eta}2$. So I set $$v(\xi,\eta):=u\left(\frac{\xi+\eta}2,\frac{\xi-\eta}2 \right)=u(x,t)$$

Differentiating twice, I get $$v_{tt}=v_{\xi \xi} - 2v_{\xi \eta}+v_{\eta \eta} \quad \text{and} \quad v_{xx}=v_{\xi \xi} + 2v_{\xi \eta}+v_{\eta \eta}.$$

Hence, $v_{tt}-v_{xx}=0$ gives $v_{\xi \eta}=0$.

Finally, we have $v(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+G(\eta)$. Hence, $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$.

Comment: It looks the same to me Let $a = x + t$, $b = x - t$, then $u(a,b) = F(a) + G(b)$

Comment: Not knowing any details of your computation, it's hard to say for sure, but do you really mean $u(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+F(\eta)$?  It seems to me that the function of $\xi$ and $\eta$ that corresponds to $u(x,t)$ should not also be named $u.$  I think that what you want to do is to define a new function $v$ defined by $v(x+t,x-t)=u(x,t).$  Then $v(\xi,\eta)=u((\xi+\eta)/2,(\xi-\eta)/2).$  If you manage to arrive at $v(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+G(\eta),$ then you can conclude that $v(x+t,x-t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ and finally that $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t).$

Comment: There are notation abuses going on. When you performed a change of variables you weren't working with $u(x,t)$ anymore, but with a $v(\xi, \eta)$. We identify the two because of tradition.

Comment: @MarkFantini I have attempted to fix my abuse of notation in my question. Does this look better somehow?

Comment: It's better, but some of those $u$'s should have been transformed to $v$'s as well. Set $u(x,t) =v(\xi, \eta)$ and then do the calculations as you would. You should arrive at $v(\xi, \eta) = F(\xi) + G(\eta)$, therefore $u(x,t) = F(x+t) + G(x-t)$.

Comment: Ohh now I understand the process with $v$'s (and fixed the rest of my work accordingly). The textbook Intro PDE by Farlow sticks with $u$'s for some reason when doing transformations, e.g. $u_{\xi \eta}=0$. Maybe the book is just being ambiguous, and should've also went along with $v$'s, which would make a clearer convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function $v$ by $v(x+t,x-t)=u(x,t).$  Defining $\xi=x+t,$ $\eta=x-t,$ we can write $v(\xi,\eta)=u((\xi+\eta)/2,(\xi-\eta)/2).$  I will take the notation $u_x$ to mean the derivative of $u$ with respect to its first argument and $u_t$ to mean the derivative of $u$ with respect to its second argument.

So
$$
u_t(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(\xi,\eta)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}v(\xi,\eta)\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}v(\xi,\eta)\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial t}=v_\xi(\xi,\eta)-v_\eta(\xi,\eta).
$$
I will not use the notations $u_\xi,$ $u_\eta,$ $v_t,$ $v_x$ since I find them somewhat ambiguous.  The notation $v_\xi$ means the derivative of $v$ with respect to its first argument; similarly, $v_\eta$ means the derivative of $v$ with respect to its second argument.  Continuing in the same way, we compute
$$
u_x(x,t)=v_\xi(\xi,\eta)+v_\eta(\xi,\eta),
$$
and then
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_{tt}(x,t)&=v_{\xi\xi}(\xi,\eta)-2v_{\xi\eta}(\xi,\eta)+v_{\eta\eta}(\xi,\eta),\\
u_{xx}(x,t)&=v_{\xi\xi}(\xi,\eta)+2v_{\xi\eta}(\xi,\eta)+v_{\eta\eta}(\xi,\eta).
\end{aligned}
$$
From $u_{tt}(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)=0$ we conclude that $-4v_{\xi\eta}(\xi,\eta)=0.$  This implies we may write $v(\xi,\eta)=F(\xi)+G(\eta).$  Therefore
$$
u(x,t)=v(x+t,x-t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t).
$$

Comment: And when I subsitute initial conditions, I have $$u(x,0)=F(x)+G(x)=g(x)$$ and $$u_t(x,0)=F'(x)-G'(x)=h(x) \implies F(x)-G(x)=\int_a^x h(y) \, dy + C.$$ So I should solve algebraically for $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, then convert to $F(x+t)$ and $G(x+t)$, and then put those both in $u(x,t)$ and I will arrive at d'Alembert's formula?

Comment: As d'Alembert's formula is given by $$u(x,t)=\frac 12 [g(x+t)+g(x-t)]+\frac 12 \int_{x-t}^{x+t} h(y) dy,$$ how can I determine, based on $g$ and $h$, that $u$ is a right-moving wave or left-moving wave?

Comment: Your method of imposing the initial conditions looks right.  The amplitude of $g(x+t)$ at a particular position, say $x=3,$ is $g(3)$ at time $t=0$ and $g(13)$ at time $t=10.$  So when time increases by $10$ units, the waveform shifts left by $10$ units.  (What was at $x=13$ at time $0$ is at $x=3$ at time $10.$)  A similar analysis of $g(x-t)$ shows that the waveform will shift right by $10$ units when time increases by $10$ units.

Comment: The function $u(x,t)$ itself is neither left-moving nor right-moving.  It is a combination of left- and right-moving waves.

Comment: I know, the problem in my book is just asking for what *conditions* of $g, h$ dictate the solution $u$ to be a left- or right-moving wave. Sorry if I was unclear initially.

Comment: Hint: both the terms in brackets and the terms coming from carrying out the integral contain left-moving and right-moving parts.  What conditions would have to hold for, say, the left moving parts to cancel out?